# Solr in cloud mode 2 machines 1 zookeeper instance

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to run solr on cloud mode using 2 seperate machines(machine1 & machine 2), i have setup a zookeeper on machine 1, now i am trying to start solr on machine 1 using the following command 
"start -c -p 8983 -z 10-13-120-212:2181 "
After this i dont see any error message initially but when i try to open solr on browser it reflect the following error
"Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Caused by:

javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"

**But at the same time if i am using the following command** 
"solr start -e cloud -z localhost:2181 -noprompt "
 solr works fine with no issues and i am able to see the solr homepage,
but with in this command when i type the ip for zookeeper instance, since i need it for solr running on machine 2 i am not able to connect to it i get the same error which i posted above
**the command which i used is
"solr start -e cloud -z 10-13-120-212:2181 -noprompt"**

Please note the only difference between working and not working is when i replace localhost with the ip of machine.

**one more thing solr version is 7.0.0 and zookeeper version is 3.4.10**

Please help me i am really stuck in this and need to finish this work really quickly.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `10-13-120-212:2181` isn't a valid IP-adress? If you're typing it with `-` between the octets, you probably mean `.`? Are you able to ping the zookeeper host? Connect to the port using telnet? There is probably also a stack trace further down with the real reason for why the core isn't starting up

Comment: yeah doing it that way only. one more thing where i can specify the port number if i want to start on a different port

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh

Comment: Which port are you thinking of? Solr? Zookeeper?

Comment: @MatsLindh, i got the bove issue fixed 2181 port was not open, its working fine now thank you...and i was asking for solr port i am using the below command "solr start -e cloud -p 8984 -z 10.13.120.212:2181 -noprompt -p 8984" but still it starts solr in 8983, kindly help on this.

Comment: The syntax from the documentation is `bin/solr start -cloud -p 7574 ..." - so that should work. Make sure that you're actually looking at the instance you started and not an existing instance that you just haven't stopped.

Comment: got the issue fixed thank you, one more thing is there a way to start two nodes by providing different port numbers using command line?

Comment: Just run the same command multiple times with different home directories and different ports. See [the examples in the tutorial which does just that](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/solr-tutorial.html).